Can you kill a Patronus?
Is there any way to destroy/kill a Patronus?
For example, can I use Avada Kedavra on it or does the Patronus simply not possess a soul that can be harmed?

Asking for a friend are we?

I have taken the liberty of editing your question so that it now asks a single answerable point. If you wish to ask whether Dementors are susceptible to Avada Kedavra, that would be a new question.

I don't think there has ever been any examples in any canon source of any attempts to use any spells on a patronus.

@SpacePhoenix - No, but I'm reasonably certain that we can work out that it is unkillable based on the fact that it is not alive.

The Patronus is not a being unto itself. It is a spell, specifically a charm (albeit a complex and difficult one to master).

The Patronus is the most famous (and famously difficult) defensive charm.  The aim is to produce a silvery-white guardian or protector, which takes the form of an animal.  The exact form of the Patronus will not be apparent until the spell has been successfully cast.  One of the most powerful defensive charms known to wizardkind, the Patronus can also be used as a messenger between wizards. As a pure, protective magical concentration of happiness and hope (the recollection of a single talisman memory is essential in its creation) it is the only spell effective against Dementors.  The majority of witches and wizards are unable to produce Patronuses and to do so is generally considered a mark of superior magical ability.
Patronus Charm - By J.K. Rowling - Originally published on Pottermore on Sep 22nd 2016

Therefore, since Avada Kedavra is unblockable by any spell (except for sacrificial love I suppose) it would destroy the conjured Patronus the same way it would destroy a simple Shield Charm.
If the wizard targeted by Avada Kedavra otherwise evades being hit by the curse, I see no reason why they would lose the ability to cast the Patronus Charm again.
